# My solution only use one for loop but why performance is low?

Tags: algorithm

The Question:

> Write a function:
>
> ```
> class Solution { 
>  public int solution(int[] A) {...} 
> }
> ```
>
> that, given an array `A` of N integers, returns the smallest positive integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in `A`.
>
> **For example:**
>
> Given `A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2]`, the function should return `5`.
> Given `A = [1, 2, 3]`, the function should return `4`.
> Given `A = [−1, −3]`, the function should return `1`.
>
> **Assume that:**
>
> `N` is an integer within the range `[1..100,000]`; each element of array `A` is an integer within the range `[−1,000,000..1,000,000]`.
>
> **Complexity:**
>
> expected worst-case *time complexity* is `O(N)`; expected worst-case *space complexity* is `O(N)` (not counting the storage required for input arguments).

May I know why I get so low score to answer the question?
My solution below:

```
public static int solution(int[] A) {
    int returnInt = 1;
    int maxInt = 0;

    if (A.length == 0) 
        return returnInt;

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) 
    {
        if (A[i] > maxInt) 
            maxInt = A[i];
    }
    
    if (maxInt < returnInt) 
        return returnInt;

    return maxInt % 2 == 0 
        ? maxInt - 1 
        : maxInt + 1;
}
```

The solution has only one for loop, I do not understand *why I get a very low score*.

Comment: Maybe you get low score because is not correct.

Comment: You give us some examples above. Run through those examples and check that your code gives the right answer to each of the examples. That will help you find the problem with your code. If any question gives you examples, always check that your code works with all the examples before submitting it.

Comment: (@rossum: `check that your code gives the right answer to each of the examples.` That it does. Regrettably.)

Comment: If you give your program the input `[1, 2]` it produces 1.

Comment: It looks like you've not tested your code enough (or perhaps not thought about it enough). Try testing it on examples like this: take the array [1, 2, 3, ..., k] for some value of k, randomly permute the array, and then remove the last few (perhaps 0, 1, 2, or 3) elements.

Comment: Yes,My solution has some error. I have fix it,thanks! I do not konw how to paste my solution here.

Comment: @HarlyChen Edit your question and paste the new code in there.

Comment: Is this Leetcode -```firstMissingPositive```  puzzle?  Then your explanation is missing the important facts....

Comment: Looking at the answers it seems like people don't understand your question. Maybe you could clarify?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HashSet<int> exists` to store all positive items of `A`; then you can check if number `1..exists.Count` is in `exists`.

**C# code:**

```
public static int solution(int[] A) {
  if (A is null || A.Length <= 0)
    return 1;

  var exists = new HashSet<int>();

  foreach (int item in A)
    if (item > 0)
      exists.Add(item);

  for (int i = 1; i <= exists.Count; ++i)
    if (!exists.Contains(i))
      return i;

  return exists.Count + 1;
}
```

In the *worst* case we have

**Time complexity:** `O(n)`, providing that we have good hash function: `foreach` loop is `O(n)` - adding to hash set is `O(1)`, `for (int i = 1; i <= exists.Count; ++i)` is `O(n)` as well - `Contains` is `O(1)` in case of hash set

**Space complexity:** `O(n)` (hash set)

If we can allow ourselves to get slightly worse time complexity - `O(n * log(n))` we can have `O(1)` space complexity only:

**C# code:**

```
public static int solution(int[] A) {
  if (A is null || A.Length <= 0)
    return 1;

  Array.Sort(A);

  for (int i = 0, prior = 0; i < A.Length; prior = Math.Clamp(A[i++], 0, A.Length)) 
    if (A[i] > 0 && A[i] != prior + 1)
      return prior + 1;

  return Math.Clamp(A[A.Length - 1] + 1, 1, A.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OP's performance is "low" certainly because it is producing the wrong answers.

`return maxInt % 2 == 0 ? maxInt - 1 : maxInt + 1;` makes little sense.

---

Simplify algorithm.

> given an array A of N integers, returns the smallest positive integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in A.

**Recognize that between values [1...N+1], there must be at least 1 value not in `A[]`.**  `A[]` has, at most, `N` different values. [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)

Cost O(N) time, O(N) more space solution, no hash table, no BST:

1. Form an array B[N+1] of T/F values - set all to false.  Index this array [1...N+1].  Cost O(N) time, O(N) more space.
2. Walk array A.  For each A[i], test if A[i] <= N (and A[i] >= 1).  If A[i] in range, set B[A[i]] = true. Cost O(N) time.
3. Walk array B. Find the first B[i] that is false, `i` is the answer.  Cost O(N) time.

---

Sample C code:

```
size_t LowestMissingPositive(size_t N, const int A[N]) {
  unsigned char Used[N + 1];
  memset(Used, 0, sizeof Used);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    if (A[i] >= 1 && (unsigned) A[i] <= N) {
      Used[A[i] - 1] = 1;
    }
  }
  for (size_t i = 0; i <= N; i++) {
    if (!Used[i]) {
      return i + 1;
    }
  }
  // Code never expected to get here.
  return N + 1;
}
```

---

Note: "each element of array A is an integer within the range [−1,000,000..1,000,000]" is not really an important stipulation other than the type of `A[]` needs to handle the range.  E.g. at least a 21-bit wide integer type.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a list `L` with all integers from `A` which are bigger than 0. `O(n)`
2. Sort `L`. `O(n lg(n))`
3. If `L` is empty, return 1. If `L[0]` is not 1, return 1.
4. Iterate through `L`. If `L[i] != i`, return i. `O(n)`

---

Total complexity = O(n + n lg(n)) = `O(n lg(n))`.

Comment: Your solution has `O(n * log(n))` time complexity which will be enough to pass performance tests and `O(n)` space complexity. However - just (an academic) remark, - it's possible to have `O(n)` time complexity and `O(n)` space complexity; or `O(n * log(n))` time complexity and `O(1)` space complexity

Comment: Yes, I know, after thinking a little bit I figured out that sorting is not needed, just filling an array or a dictionary with the given numbers and then searching for a case where `input[i] != i` should do the job in O(n).